# How to set custom text notification sounds with a Samsung Galaxy S22?

Tags: samsung, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s, custom-sounds

I just purchased a Samsung Galaxy S22. It runs Android 12 and One UI 4.1.

What I am trying to do is use a custom notification sound for my text messages (Google Messages). I want a custom sound for one specific person and another for everyone else. I had this previously on my Galaxy S8.

Unfortunately this does not work for me. I have added the sounds I wish to use to my phone's storage. This includes custom ringtones. Those do work as I am able to select them when choosing a ringtone. I can see them in my list of available ringtones.  But the sounds I have added for notifications do not appear in the list of available notification sounds.

I have tried placing them in the following locations:

- /root/sdcard/Notifications
- /root/sdcard/Ringtones
- /root/sdcard/Android/media
- /root/sdcard/Android/media/Notifications

It's this still possible to do? If so, what am I missing?

Comment: Can someone with enough reputation create the `samsung-galaxy-s-22` tag for me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out what I was missing is that the format of the file *must* be MP3. Mine were .wav files which worked on the older OS but not in the newer OS.